# Set response body in case of error in spring

Tags: spring, exception, servlets, kotlin

I have an api in spring, returning a bytearray. In case any error happens, is it logical/possible to add a response body ?

eg:

```
@GetMapping(value = ["path"], produces = ["application/pdf"])
@ResponseBody
fun method(@PathVariable("varib") var: String?,
           request: HttpServletRequest?, response: 
HttpServletResponse?): ByteArray? {

   // some method which will return a byte arrat
    return pdf
}

@ExceptionHandler(RUnTimeException::class)
fun errorHandler(e: Exception,response: ServletRespons) {
response?.setHeader('someheader','value')
}
```

Is it possible to add a response body in case of exception ? from inside  'errorHandler' method ?is it logical ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add ControllerAdvice:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandlingAdvice {
    private final Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(Exception ex) {
        return handleException(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(String message, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        log.error("Error: " + message);
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.of(Instant.now(clock), message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, httpStatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Spring you are using, you don't need a `@ResponseBody`. You should rather use a `@ControllerAdvice` that help manage all your exceptions in your differents layers (repository, service, controller). You can define a custom response message that will represent your `@Responsebody`. I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191230/should-http-codes-be-used-to-represent-business-failure/53194350#53194350) can help you.