# Spring Java Rest Handle invalid type at deserialization

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I'm working on a java REST API for registering users. I'm trying to check if the User sent to POST has all its fields valid so it can be saved to db, but I cannot find a way to handle error if one of its fields is of invalid type.

My model User.java

```
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column
private String description;
@Column
private String date_joined;
@Column
private double age;
//setters and getters
}
```

User Resource Method:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response postUser(User User)
{  
    //validate User fields and save to db
    // if valid return following, else send Bad Request
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(User).build();
}
```

I'm using ajax to send the data the following way:

```
{
"date_joined":"27/12/19",
"description":"Currently looking for job",
"age":30
}
```

It works nice with this example but I want to validate that the data sent is of invalid type, for example:

```
{
"date_joined":"27/12/19",
"description":"Currently looking for job",
"age": "thirty"
}
```

This gives the following error

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of double from String value 'thirty': not a valid Double value
```

Is there a way to catch those kinds of errors? So later I can for example send a message to the user that they sent invalid data

Comment: Search for `ExceptionHandler`, `@ControllerAdvice` and possibly also `@Valid`. Add spring/spring-boot tag if this is Spring related

Comment: I would do this validation on the client in javascript to save the server workload

Comment: Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191230/should-http-codes-be-used-to-represent-business-failure/53194350#53194350), it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Could a solution be to catch the exception and return an error message in case you get a JsonMappingException?

```
try {
   return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(User).build();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
   // Return a 4xx statuscode to indicate a client error and some json containing e.getMessage()
}
```

Please let me know if this is usefull! Thanks!

:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a way. We can write own custom deserializer.

I have written an deserializer/validator for email validation.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

public class EmailValidator2 extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        System.out.println("Intercepting deserlization to validate email....");

        ObjectCodec objectCodec = jsonParser.getCodec();

        JsonNode jsonNode = objectCodec.readTree(jsonParser);

        String value = jsonNode.asText();



        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value) && (!org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(value))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Email address is invalid");
        }

        return jsonNode.asText();
    }
}





import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
@Service
public class CustomSerializerAndDeserializerRegistry extends SimpleModule {

    public CustomSerializerAndDeserializerRegistry() {
        this.addDeserializer(String.class, new EmailValidator2());

    }

}


public class User{

    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using = EmailValidator2.class)
    @ExceptionHandler
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I can help more if needed.