# LocalDate validation issue

Tags: java, date, validation, localdate

I have been stuck on this issue for some time. I am using `LocalDate` to accept date inputs from user via a REST endpoint. I want to validate this date to check if it's `null`, `empty` string or `invalid` date such as `Feb 30`. I have managed to get it to work for valid date values but in case of invalid input, it's throwing `400 Bad Request` in response which is coming from internal classes of Java so I don't have any control over it. If you could please let me know if I am missing something or doing it wrong, I will really appreciate it.

This is called method in my controller - annotated with @Valid:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value="/add")
public ResponseEntity<PSResponse> add(@Valid @RequestBody PSRequest request) throws Exception {
    setServiceID(SERVICE_HANDLER_ID);
    request.setRequestType("add");
    PSResponse response = (PSResponse) invokeInternal(request);
}
```

This is class for my request object

```
public class PSRequest {
@NotNull(message = "fromDate cannot be null")
protected LocalDate fromDate;

@NotNull(message = "toDate cannot be null")
protected LocalDate toDate;}
```

Valid JSON input

```
"fromDate":2020-10-16"
"toDate":"2021-10-16"
```

Invalid JSON input date formats

```
"fromDate":null,
"toDate":"2021-02-30"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the date format ISO 9601?  Do you need to validate some order relationship between the from & to dates? 

Btw, you seem to be missing a quote in your valid JSON example.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing and it is normal to get a `400 bad request`.
Why? Because you are working with Rest Endpoint which is based on `Http` protocol

A `Bad request` means that your `Http` request is not correct due to many reason such as : **invalid parameters**. The best practice is to send a clear message to the user explaining what happened after the request he send to the server. To do that you can use [RestControllerAdvice](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-restcontrolleradvice/) to intercept all your exceptions and map it to `Http` status codes.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191230/should-http-codes-be-used-to-represent-business-failure/53194350#53194350) for more details.

Comment: There are bunch of other fields in the input as well which can result in a 400 bad request. Hence I would like to keep control in my code so I can send a custom message specific to these date fields to the user. 

With these dates defined as Strings, I am able to do it. But with LocalDate datatype, Java takes control even before it hits my code and throws this 400. That's why I added @NotNull annotation in my request but that did not help.

Comment: You can handle the exception by explicitly throwing it if really know your use case. There is any issue if Java handle this exception. You can handle this exception in your `RestControllerAdvice` and return a customized message.

Answer (score 0):

In order to suppress the build-in validations, you can recieve `String` from the frontend, and only then do your code: `LocalDate.parse(fromDate)`, catch the `DateTimeParseException` and handle it as you wish.

Another option is to remove the `@Valid`

By the way, what's wrong with `@Valid` ? Don't you want to have 400 in return anyway ?! or you'd like to control the body message with the 400 ?

Comment: I would like to keep control in my code since 400 can happen due to other reasons as well. There are bunch of other fields in the input as well.